# mysql UPDATE query not working for image upload via php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

Trying to write an image upload to mysql via php,
trying to use the user id to UPDATE the row.
However, keeps giving this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(image_type,image, image_size, image_name) VALUES ('images/1459926006.png','png'' at line 1

Just can't see what is the Syntax error.

PHP:

```
   function upload(){
/*** check if a file was uploaded ***/
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) && getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) != false)
    {
    /***  get the image info. ***/
    $size = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    /*** assign our variables ***/
    $type = $size['mime'];
    $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
    $size = $size[3];
    $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $maxsize = 99999999;


    /***  check the file is less than the maximum file size ***/
    if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize )
        {
        /*** connect to db ***/
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table", 'username', 'password');

                /*** set the error mode ***/
                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            /*** our sql query ***/
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users (image_type,image, image_size, image_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?) WHERE user_id=?"); 

        /*** bind the params ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(5, $_SESSION['user_id']);

        /*** execute the query ***/
        $stmt->execute();
        }
    else
        {
        /*** throw an exception is image is not of type ***/
        throw new Exception("File Size Error");
        }
    }
else
    {
    // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
    throw new Exception("Unsupported Image Format!");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `update query` as `insert query` syntax both are different

Change

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users (image_type,image, image_size, image_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?) WHERE user_id=?");
```

to

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET image_type=?, image=?, image_size=1 ,image_name=?  WHERE user_id=?");
```

And you are binding `$stmt->bindParam(4, $name);` two times

```
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);
       // $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);// comment it
        $stmt->bindParam(5, $_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Check [Update query syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Comment: No error now, but still no update. I must be getting the user id wrong.

Comment: Yes check your session id!! make sure you have start session at the top of your page!!

Comment: lol :) I made sure I do. but I guess i'm referencing it incorrectly.

Comment: Would helping me with getting the id? I've been looking a the manuals but just can't get it

Comment: yaa sure!! post a new question regarding your id issue with your relevant code!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446034/getting-mysql-row-id-for-where-clause-on-update-via-php

Answer (score 1):

Your update SQL query syntax is wrong. Change your query as below:

From :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users (image_type,image, image_size, image_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?) WHERE user_id=?");
```

Change to:

```
UPDATE `users`   
   SET `image_type` = ?,
       `image` = ?,
       `image_size` = ?,
       `image_name` = ? 
 WHERE `user_id` = ?
```

Try it now!!!!!